# What's the difference between getline and std::istream::operator>>()?

Tags: c++, cin, istream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string username;
   cout<< "username" ;
   cin >> username; 
}
```

So I was curious on what's the difference between these two codes, I heard it's the same thing but if it is then why two ways of doing it then?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{  
   string username;
   cout << "username" ;
   getline (cin,username) ;
}
```

Comment: _"What's the difference between getline and cin?"_ A similar one as that of an _apple and an elephant_.

Answer (score 12):

The difference is that`std::getline` — as the name suggests — reads a *line* from the given input stream (which could be,  well, `std::cin`) and `operator>>` reads a *word*<sup>1</sup>.

That is, `std::getline` reads till a newline is found and `operator>>` reads till a space (as defined by `std::isspace`) and is found. Both remove their respective delimiter from the stream but don't put it in the output buffer.

<sup>1. Note that `>>` can also read numbers — `int`, `short`, `float`, `char`, etc.</sup>

Comment: _"and operator>> reads a word."_ If applied to a `std::string` variable, yes.

Comment: More precisely, `operator >>' reads till a space or a newline character is found.

Comment: @Svalbard: That is **not** precise at all. `operator >>` reads till a *space*, **as defined by std::isspace**, is found. That is precise. Also, `std::isspace` depends on the current locale, which could define anything to be a space. You can even define all the lowercase letters as space, then `operator>>` would skip all lowercase letters.

Answer (score 7):

the `>>` operator of `std::istream` read **space separated** strings.

`getline` reads up to a given separator ('\n' as default).

So `getline` admits a string containing spaces, the >> operator doesn't

Answer (score 3):

There are actually two `getline` functions: one in the many `stream` classes and one free function. The stream `getline` functions take as a parameter a char* array into which it reads the characters and the max number of characters. The free function takes as a parameter a `std::string` so it resizes the string when it is needed. Both functions can take optionally a third parameter, which is a delimiter (`'\n'` by default).

The input operator `operator>>` is for reading *formatted* input. For example, if you run `int i; std::cin >> i;` it will try to convert the input into an integer whereas the `getline` functions will read it s characters. The input operator also by default removes all white spaces. It is also used for custom serialisation of classes into strings as shown [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/input_output_operators_overloading.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Simple Answer:
getline: As the name suggests, gets everything till it encounters a "\n" newline character. Here, input is always considered as a string.
So, if you write:

```
string someStr;
getline(cin, someStr);  //here if you enter 55, it will be considered as someStr="55";
```

">>" (Bitwise right shift Operator): Is smart and dumb at the same time.
It will get input in any Basic Data types that you define, but it will stop at the first non Data Type char encountered.
E.g.

```
int someInt;
std::cin >> someInt;  //here if you enter "55some", >> will only consider someInt=55;
```

So, if you write:

```
string someStr;
cin >> someStr;
```

here, if you enter, "I am Batman", cin understands that "I" is a string, but " " (space is not), so it stops at I and you will get someStr="I".

***IMP Point:***
If you use >> and getline back to back you will run into problems.
for >>, even the "\n" (newline char) is not a Data type.
So, if you write,

```
int someStr, someStr2;
std::cin >> someStr;   //here you enter "Batman"
getline(cin, someStr2);  //here you enter "Bruce"
```

since, >> does not recognize "\n" char, it will only see "Batman" and exit the buffer, leaving the "\n" for someStr2. So, someStr2 will not get "Bruce", but ""(new line char).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it might be necessary to read a line just after using the `cin`, and in that case if you use `getline()` after `cin>>` then you might run in a problem where you get nothing in the `getline()` variable. To avoid that you can do the following:

```
cin>>consoleInputVariable;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin,getLineVariable);
```

In short, see the use of `ignore()` as it comes quite handy.