# How do I fix this weird while loop error?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have a while loop that asks the user's query and takes in a response, could be a word, could be a sentence. The output is boggling me.

```
std::string response;

while (response != "!quit")
    {
        cout << "Query? ";
        cin >> response;
        if (response == "!quit")
        {
            cout << "Thank you for using this program!";
            exit(0);
        }
    }
```

The output for this looks like this:

```
Query? how are you
Query? Query? Query? how are you today
Query? Query? Query? Query? hi
Query?
```

why is it printing out "query" for the same number of words as the response?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005015/whats-the-difference-between-getline-and-stdistreamoperator

Comment: How is `response` defined?

Comment: @DarkAtom as a string

Comment: @Alexander You mean a `std::string`?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [C++ “cin” only reads the first word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469264/c-cin-only-reads-the-first-word), or this: [std::cin.getline( ) vs. std::cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745858/stdcin-getline-vs-stdcin)

Comment: **Debugging tip:** Your loop is controlled by the `response` variable. When the loop seems to be misbehaving, take a look at the value of that variable (e.g. `cout << "response is '" << response <<"'.\n";` right after you read it from `cin`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::cin` is going to read until it meats a whitespace.

So when you input "how are you ", `cin` is going to be called thrice, so that it consumes all three whitespaces. So the first `cin` will read "how ", the second "are ", and the third "you ".

So what teaches you is that in order to read a sentence, you need another approach, e.g. by using [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/), like this:

```
std::getline(std::cin, response)
```

Read more in [What's the difference between getline and std::istream::operator>>()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005015/whats-the-difference-between-getline-and-stdistreamoperator)

---

PS: Note the trailing newline character that might appear after reading a number with `cin`, which you might want to consume, e.g. by using `getchar();`.

Answer (score 3):

*It could be a word, could be a sentence.*

When you want to read a word, you can use `cin >> response;`. This will stop reading at the next whitespace character found.

When you want to read a sentence (an entire line), you need to use `getline(cin, response);`. This will stop reading at the next new-line `\n` character found.

Therefore, since you are expecting one input on a single line, use the second function.

EDIT: Also, please note! When using `getline()` after a non-string I/O operation (like `cin >> n;`, where `n` is an `int` variable), you need to know that the non-string I/O functions don't "eat" the `\n` character. `getline()` will find it, consume it and stop, so it is best to eat it yourself with an empty `cin.getline();` call.