# Issue with Converting string to float when pasting in values

Tags: c++

I have this program I made and have been using the online compiler to run it,
https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/#google_vignette

I am aiming to take in 5 values using `getline`,
convert these to floats, and get a total/ average.
i also want the code to be reusable, meaning as long as there is an input run through the above
(also the it has loads of crap left in )

when i input values 1 by 1 (i enter a number then hit enter) the code works as it should,
but pasting them in, i get this error;

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stof
Aborted
dash: 2: 5.0: not found
dash: 4: 15.0: not found
dash: 6: 20.0: not found
dash: 8: 10.0: not found
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i;
    string token, n;
    float n2, total;
    cout<<"Input 5 floating numbers"<<endl;
    while(true){
    for( i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
        getline(cin, n);
        //cout<<n.length()<<endl;
        token = n.substr(0, n.find("\n"));
        n2 = stof(n);
        //cout<<n<<endl;
        //n2 = stof(n);
        //cout<<typeid(n).name()<<endl;
        if (n.length() > 0) {
            n2 = stof(n);
            total = total + n2;
        } else cout<<"n2 = "<<n<<endl;
        
        //cout<<n2<<endl;
    }
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2);
    cout<<"Total = "<<total<<endl;
    cout<<"Average = "<<total/i<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
//input sample values
/* 
10.0
5.0
15.0
20.0
10.0
*/
```

I have tried to see if the lines carry the `\n` by checking the length but they don't?
I want to be able to paste in 5 values at a time.

Comment: Why do you want use `getline()`? For your purpose `cin` seems more suited. With `getline()`, if user give more than one number in one go, you need to handle that explicitly and that handling is missing from your code.

Comment: ah right ok thanks, i used cin instead and it works as i would like it too, why do getline and cin act differently in this case?

Comment: you can google and easily find the difference between `getline` and `istream` overload of `>>` operator. To start with, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005015/whats-the-difference-between-getline-and-stdistreamoperator). There are other major issues in your code and one of them if infinite `while` loop and other one is user input validation. The `while` loop should have some logical end and user input should be validated properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are better ways to do this, but lets stick to your logic as much as we can.

I don't think I understood if you want to keep this running infinitely, or you want to exit after taking 5 floats and doing the calculation that is being done.
If you want to keep doing this without breaking, then you need to reset the context as below:

```
cout<<"Total = "<<total<<endl;
cout<<"Average = "<<total/i<<endl;
i = 0; // The for loop won't work first time onwards if you don't set i to 0
total = 0; // Flush the previous total as you may want to add and average over 5 floats
```

Instead, if you want to exit:

```
cout<<"Total = "<<total<<endl;
cout<<"Average = "<<total/i<<endl;
break;
```

**Suggestion:** Whenever you are taking user input via stdin, its usually a good idea to have an exit/abort path.
A very crude way would be:

```
if((n == "quit") || (n == "Quit") || (n == "QUIT") || 
   (n == "abort") || (n == "Abort") || (n == "ABORT") || 
   (n == "Q") || (n == "q")) {
   cout<<"Aborted, bye"<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

**Improvement:**

You should just use `std::cin` rather than using `getline()`.

You can/should `getline` when you intend to specify how many characters should be read from stdin and the place where these characters should be put.
However, `getline` returns when the end of a line is reached or there are no more characters to read from or the specified number of characters is read.

Comment: nice one mate cheers

Comment: @junaidumar -- If this answers your question, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> *terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'*

This is the exception thrown by `stof()` when no conversion could be performed.

There are several issue in your code. Lets discuss them one by one:

**First**:

You are using `getline()` for user input. When user give more than `1` input numbers in one go, like this - `10.0 5.0 15.0 20.0 10.0` it will be passed to `stof()` and `stof()` will convert only as many characters as possible to form a valid floating-point representation and convert them to floating-point value. It will stop conversion at first space character. That means, only `10.0` will be converted and rest input will be discarded.

May you should use `cin >>` which seems a good fit for your case because `istream` operator `>>` read till a whitespace character encountered and in the next call it read the leftover data, if there is any, in the input buffer.

**Second**:

`stof()` may throw exception and you are not handling them. When exception occur, will result in program termination. No proper handling of invalid input or partial invalid input (e.g. `10.0ab`).

**Third**:

Infinite `while` loop. There should be some logical end of loop (may be, a conditional `break` statement).

**Fourth**:

Variable `total` need to be initialize with `0` for every new set of user input.

**Fifth**:

`using namespace std;` is considered to be a bad practice. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

You can do:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    char c{'y'};
    
    do {
        if (c == 'y') {
            float total{};
            int i{}, ii{};
            std::cout << "Enter 5 float number : \n";
            for (; i < 5; ++i) {
                std::cout << i + 1 << " : ";
                std::cin >> s;
                 
                try {
                    std::size_t pos{};
                    const float n{std::stof(s, &pos)};
                    if (s.length() != pos) {
                        std::cout << "Input " << s << " partially converted to float : " << n << "; pos: " << pos << '\n';
                    }

                    total = total + n;
                    // total may overflow
                    // leaving it up to you to handle this scenario
                }
                catch (std::invalid_argument const& ex) {
                    std::cout << "std::invalid_argument::what(): " << ex.what() << '\n';
                    std::cout << "Skipping this input..\n";
                    ++ii;
                }
                catch (std::out_of_range const& ex) {
                    std::cout << "std::out_of_range::what(): " << ex.what() << '\n';
                    std::cout << "Skipping this input..\n";
                    ++ii;
                }
            }
            
            std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
            std::cout << "Total = " << total << '\n';
            std::cout << "No. of valid input = " << (i - ii) << '\n';
            if ((i - ii) > 0) {
                std::cout << "Average = " << total / (i - ii) << '\n';
            } else {
                std::cout << "No average\n";
            }
            // to discard the extra left over input
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        
        std::cout << "Do you want to continue [y/n] : \n";
        std::cin >> s;
        if ((s.length() > 1) || 
            ((s[0] != 'n') && (s[0] != 'N') &&
            (s[0] != 'y') && (s[0] != 'Y'))) {
            s[0] = '\0';
            std::cout << "Invalid input, try again..\n";
        }
        
        c = std::tolower(static_cast <unsigned char> (s[0]));

    } while (c != 'n');

    return 0;
}
```